# Android Listview Search filter

Tags: android, listview, search, filter, search-engine

I am trying to make a list view search for Android. I have found many tutorials that do just that where 
a search-bar is placed at the top and if you type in the box the results get filtered.

In my app I want to click on given items after filtering has been completed, I have implemented setOnItemClickListener. The issue is that after filtering the position of each class that I want to open changes and the incorrect pages open. I was unable to find a solution....

Here is the jave code:

```
package com.equations.search;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EquationsSearch extends Activity {
// List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;

// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.equations_search);

    // Listview Data
    final String products[] = { "Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X",
            "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE" };

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.equations_search_list, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            EquationsSearch.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChange(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // if(position == 1)
            String openClass = products[position];
            if (openClass.equals("HTC Wildfire S")) {
                // code specific to first list item
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), A6262.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

and here is the xml equations_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Editext for Search -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search products.."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<!-- List View -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and equations_search_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Single ListItem -->

<!-- Product Name -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `products[position]`, use `adapter.getItem(position)`. When the `ListView` is not in filter mode, those two things will be the same. But, in filter mode, `getItem()` will take the filtering into account.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, I spend at least 2 weeks trying to figure this out :D

Comment: My app now will be awesome (or at least as awesome search lists go)

Comment: Sir I also have exactly the same problem! But the difference is that each list view has data like name, address and age. I just want to fetch the name in textview wen i click that particular item. So under setOnItemClickListener when i use adapter.getItem(position) i fetch not only the name but also address and age. I wanna know to filter it so as to extract the name part. All these name, address and age were arrays. So when I tried using TextView tv.setText(name[position)] the results went haywire during the search opeartion

Answer (score 1):

The ListAdapter will change the relative position of the items it currently shows due to the filtering. You should always use `getItem(position)` to retrieve the correct item.

Comment: Sir I also have exactly the same problem! But the difference is that each list view has data like name, address and age. I just want to fetch the name in textview wen i click that particular item. So under setOnItemClickListener when i use adapter.getItem(position) i fetch not only the name but also address and age. I wanna know to filter it so as to extract the name part. All these name, address and age were arrays. So when I tried using TextView tv.setText(name[position)] the results went haywire during the search opeartion