# Android how to implement expandable listview filter search?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, android-search

I am trying to develop an android application with expandable list view able to search group items from filter search.

I have found many tutorials that do just that where a search-bar is placed at the top and if you type in the box the results get filtered.

I able find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467293/not-able-to-implement-search-in-expandable-list-view) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057148/android-listview-search-filter) for something very related to my problem and i have followed up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356262/how-to-use-edit-text-as-search-box-in-expandable-listviewandroid) way to implementation.

I was unable to get successful result. its not working without prompting any errors. please suggest me some tutorial to achieve this task.

appreciate any help..

Comment: what kind of error do you get by using the tuts?

Comment: there are no any errors.. i need to know the correct way to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Implementing your own filtered searching can be annoying, tricky, and buggy if not done correctly. Unfortunately Android does not provide a filterable adapter for use with the `ExpandableListView` which means you need to roll your own solution. Rather then going through all that pain, I suggest using the [RolodexArrayAdapter](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters).  It's a full fledged `ExpandableListAdapter` that adds filtering support (as well as many other things).  Additionally there's a demo app with plenty of example code to show the various ways in which to use it.